# Dependency class not found on uploaded WAR file to Heroku with latest Jetty and Jersey

Tags: java, maven, heroku, jersey, jetty

I have a simple web app developed in Java language and it utilizes the library dependency of [DL4J](https://deeplearning4j.org/) and [ND4J](http://nd4j.org/) to read and process a certain text file (size of text file is huge, about 100-200mb) located inside the WEB-INF folder of a WAR file. I'm using Maven build tools, and I included all the necessary dependency in my POM.xml :

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.example</groupId>
<artifactId>simple-heroku-webapp</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>simple-heroku-webapp</name>


<properties>
    <nd4j.version>0.6.0</nd4j.version>
    <dl4j.version>0.6.0</dl4j.version>
    <jersey.version>2.23.2</jersey.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <jetty.version>9.0.6.v20130930</jetty.version>
</properties>


<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-bom</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>



<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>jetty-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>${jetty.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>jetty-webapp</artifactId>
        <version>${jetty.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.test-framework.providers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-test-framework-provider-bundle</artifactId>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.deeplearning4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>deeplearning4j-ui</artifactId>
        <version>${dl4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.deeplearning4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>deeplearning4j-nlp</artifactId>
        <version>${dl4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.nd4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>nd4j-native</artifactId>
        <version>${nd4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.nd4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>nd4j-common</artifactId>
        <version>${nd4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <finalName>simple-heroku-webapp</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.1</version>
            <inherited>true</inherited>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <includeScope>compile</includeScope>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals><goal>copy</goal></goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <artifactItems>
                            <artifactItem>
                                <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
                                <artifactId>jetty-runner</artifactId>
                                <version>9.0.0.M5</version>
                                <destFileName>jetty-runner.jar</destFileName>
                            </artifactItem>
                        </artifactItems>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${jetty.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <contextPath>/</contextPath>
                <webApp>
                    <contextPath>/</contextPath>
                    <webInfIncludeJarPattern>.*/.*jersey-[^/]\.jar$</webInfIncludeJarPattern>
                </webApp>
                <war>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}.war</war>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.heroku.sdk</groupId>
            <artifactId>heroku-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

I tested the apps on local jetty server in WAR format using jetty-runner, and every GET request works as expected. And so I deploy it to Heroku using `heroku:deploy-war` from Intellij IDE. Deploy is successfull, no error/warning logs displayed.
After that, I navigate to the main page on the Heroku link (calling GET method on page not utilizing DL4J and ND4J), and the page works. But when I try to call a GET request on methods that utilizes DL4J and ND4J libraries, the browser page display this error stating the following NoClassFound error :

```
HTTP Status 500 - org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.nd4j.linalg.factory.Nd4j

    type Exception report

    message org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.nd4j.linalg.factory.Nd4j

    description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

    exception

    javax.servlet.ServletException: org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.nd4j.linalg.factory.Nd4j
        org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:489)
        org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:427)
        org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:388)
        org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:341)
        org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:228)

    root cause

    org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.nd4j.linalg.factory.Nd4j
        org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.internal.ResponseWriter.rethrow(ResponseWriter.java:278)
        org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.internal.ResponseWriter.failure(ResponseWriter.java:260)
        org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$Responder.process(ServerRuntime.java:509)
        org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$2.run(ServerRuntime.java:334)
        org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
        org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
        org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
        org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
        org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
        org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:317)
        org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:305)
        org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1154)
        org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:473)
        org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:427)
        org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:388)
        org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:341)
        org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:228)

    root cause

    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.nd4j.linalg.factory.Nd4j
        org.deeplearning4j.models.embeddings.loader.WordVectorSerializer.loadTxt(WordVectorSerializer.java:1578)
        org.deeplearning4j.models.embeddings.loader.WordVectorSerializer.loadTxtVectors(WordVectorSerializer.java:1502)
        com.example.MyResource.train(MyResource.java:61)
        sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory$1.invoke(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:81)
        org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher$1.run(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:144)
        org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:161)
        org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$TypeOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:205)
        org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:99)
        org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:389)
        org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:347)
        org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:102)
        org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$2.run(ServerRuntime.java:326)
        org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
        org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
        org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
        org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
        org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
        org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:317)
        org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:305)
        org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1154)
        org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:473)
        org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:427)
        org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:388)
        org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:341)
        org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:228)

    note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/8.0.30 logs.
```

To be more specific, it only happens whenever I call the `train` method from the following source code :

```
package com.example;
import org.deeplearning4j.models.embeddings.loader.WordVectorSerializer;
import org.deeplearning4j.models.embeddings.wordvectors.WordVectors;

import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.QueryParam;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collection;

/**
 * Root resource (exposed at "myresource" path)
 */

@Path("test")
public class MyResource {

    WordVectors wordVectors=null;

    String loc="/WEB-INF/glove.6B.50d.txt";
    @javax.ws.rs.core.Context
    ServletContext context;


    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String getIt() {
        return  "Test";
     }

    @GET
    @Path("train")
    @Produces("text/plain")
    public String train(){


        String fullPath = context.getRealPath(loc);
        File file = new File(fullPath);
        try {
            wordVectors = WordVectorSerializer.loadTxtVectors(file);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Collection<String> lst = wordVectors.wordsNearest("day", 20);


        return Arrays.toString(lst.toArray());
    }

}
```

Class launching the Jetty Embedded Container :

```
package com.example.heroku;

import org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server;
import org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        String webPort = System.getenv("PORT");
        if (webPort == null || webPort.isEmpty()) {
            webPort = "8080";
        }

        final Server server = new Server(Integer.valueOf(webPort));
        final WebAppContext root = new WebAppContext();

        root.setContextPath("/");
        root.setParentLoaderPriority(true);

        final String webappDirLocation = "src/main/webapp/";
        root.setDescriptor(webappDirLocation + "/WEB-INF/web.xml");
        root.setResourceBase(webappDirLocation);

        server.setHandler(root);
        server.start();
        server.join();
    }
}
```

The error seems to be pointing that one of the class from the library of ND4J are not accessible although I already checked `WEB-INF/lib` folder, and all `ND4J` libraries are there. Any guidance/help/tips would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried to extract the jar inside lib and see if the class is actually there? Maybe the version is different or the deploy went wrong for some reason.

Comment: @FabioF. Hi Fabio, I have extracted the jar inside the lib folder and the class is there.

Comment: Can you share your `Procfile`?

Comment: Oh maybe you are deploying with `heroku:deploy-war`?

Comment: @codefinger Here's my Procfile : web: java -cp target/classes:target/dependency/* com.example.heroku.Main. Also when I try to execute the command on my command prompt, it doesn't work, saying the Main class is not found despite being at the correct referenced location. The app works if I use mvn jetty:run-war.

And yes, I'm deploying using heroku:deploy-war .

Comment: With `deploy-war` the `Procfile` is ignored, and the WAR is run in a Tomcat container. I don't think that's what you want. try `mvn heroku:deploy` instead?

Comment: @codefinger alright, i'll try using `heroku:deploy` and will let you know how it goes.. One question though, since by using `deploy-war` already allows my resource and all classes to be packaged into the `WAR` file, what are the side effects when `Procfile` is ignored in this context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like the standard Servlet WebApp Classloader isolation is doing its job.

You have to be aware of *where* your class is, is it being loaded from the Server classpath, or the WebApp's classpath.

When you used ...

```sh
java -cp target/classes:target/dependency/* com.example.heroku.Main
```

The classes and jars defined in `target/classes:target/dependency/*` are on the Server Classpath, and as such, the WebApp is forbidden from seeing those from the Server Classpath.

However ...

You also declared `root.setParentLoaderPriority(true);` which breaks out of the Servlet WebApp Classloader isolation, but you now have 2 copies of those classes, in different places.  Once from the Server Classpath and once again from the WebApp's Classpath.  There are many libraries which will not function if some of their classes are part of 1 classpath and some are part of another.

If you are going to be using this [embedded-jetty](/questions/tagged/embedded-jetty) approach, consider having your `WEB-INF/lib` completely empty, or not declaring the classes on your Server Classpath as well.

When you ran ...

```sh
mvn jetty:run-war
```

Then the classes are part of your WebApp classpath, the WebApp can see them, and the server classpath has no copy of them.